# react native callback dispatch which is right?

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

which way is correct ?

way 1:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const add = useCallback(() => {

  }, [dispatch]);
```

way2:

```
  const dispatch = useCallback(() => {
    return useDispatch();
  }, []);

  const add = useCallback(() => {

  }, [dispatch]);
```

................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1):

The first way for sure: hooks can only be called in the context of a functional component, and not in the body of another hook call (hence you cannot nest useDispatch inside useCallback)